# Lazy Load sometimes don't work

Tags: plugins, post-thumbnails

recently I implented lazy load script into my wordpress blog through query posts. Well it is working, but sometimes javascript will not just work.

Actually I have these images in sidebar aka images of products on the right http://affgadgets.com/rankpay

Funny is when it will not load lazy load script it will also not load another important scripts on the page, do you know what is the problem ?

Comment: How are you loading Lazy Load? `wp_enqueue_scripts`? A plugin? I'm not seeing it loaded on that page at all.

Comment: I have it custom js file

Comment: using this http://pastebin.com/xst2zczE

Comment: Console is showing "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" on `$("img.lazy").lazyload();` in your noindex.js file. You've got some other errors too that you'll want to square away.

Comment: what that means ? uncaught referenceerror ?

Comment: I was mistaken, Lazy Load is receiving the following error: "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function ". There's a problem with your Lazy Load script. Since this isn't a WordPress issue, I'm not going to troubleshoot that beyond suggesting you go grab a fresh copy of Lazy Load - I have no clue if your existing one has been modified - (http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload), or maybe just try installing the Lazy Load plugin (https://wordpress.org/plugins/jquery-image-lazy-loading/). You have other javascript errors which will probably cause you additional problems as well.

Comment: you've got a jQuery script in your head tag that occurs before jQuery is included in the page.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that can cause the lazy load script not to load. Check these few things:

- Make sure that the lazy load script is loaded in the header of your
  website. It is the most common place to load lazy load scripts
  because it ensures that script is loaded before anything else.
- Check the loading order of your scripts. If you have other scripts
  that are loading before the lazy load script,that may prevent it from
  loading. So please try changing the loading order and see if that
  fixes the problem.
- Check your website's hosting configuration. If your website is hosted
  on a shared hosting plan, it's possible that your hosting provider is
  blocking the lazy load script.

Hope this helps!